# Delete data from a sheet in google sheets with API - using Postman

Tags: api, google-sheets, postman

I would like to erase all the data of a sheet in a google sheet
via the googlet sheets APIs: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear

Unfortunately I can not select the id of my sheet.
I used the proposed method: POST [https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetid}/values/{range}](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%7Bspreadsheetid%7D/values/%7Brange%7D): clear

but it only removes the data from my first sheet.

How can I put the id of my other leaves in the method?

[My google sheets ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJhbB.png)

[My first sheets in my google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hi6.png)

[ID of my second sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u6UM.png)

[My second sheets in my google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oBk3.png)

Comment: At "Method: spreadsheets.values.clear", the requirement parameters are Spreadsheet ID and range. You can see the Spreadsheet ID from the Spreadsheet. And, the range is A1Notation. These are not the sheet ID. So, I cannot understand `the id of my sheet` you are thinking. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike,
Thanks for help me.
Don’t worry, maybe I’m the one who doesn’t express myself well.

In the command :
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetid}/values/{range}: clear

I added screenshots to help you in my post.
I add the id of my sheets but I do not specify exactly that it sheet I want clear. 
For example we can see that on my google sheet there is an ID 'edit#gid=0' which represents my first sheet and on my 2nd sheet there is the id 961658123. (What is blurred is the id of all my google sheets {spreadsheetid})

Comment: The post method just allows me to clear the 1st sheet of my google sheets and not the other sheets
I don’t know if it’s possible to add in the method the id of my 2nd sheet?
Example: 
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetid}/sheets/{sheetsID}/values/{range}: clear
(This command does not work)
I’m sorry if I’m not very clear.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reply, the request of "Method: spreadsheets.values.clear" is as follows.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:clear
```

> `spreadsheetId` : The spreadsheet the updates were applied to.

> `range`: The range (in A1 notation) that was cleared. (If the request was for an unbounded range or a ranger larger than the bounds of the sheet, this will be the actual range that was cleared, bounded to the sheet's limits.)

In this case, it is not required to use the sheet ID. The sheet name is used.

From your showing images, it seems that the sheet names of your 1st and 2nd sheet are `Feuille 1` and `Feuille 2`, respectively. For example, when you want to clear 2nd sheet of `Feuille 2`, please use the following request.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Feuille%202:clear
```

#### Note:

- For example, when you want to retrieve the sheet names from a Google Spreadsheet, you can use "Method: spreadsheets.get". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.clear](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/clear)

Comment: Thanks for your help Tanaike!
That’s exactly what I was looking for.
I set up this method to clean lines in my sheet : https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{ spreadsheetsid}/values/{sheetsname}!A2:Z1000:clear